# React-Query: useInfiniteQuery

Tags: react-query

So, I have looked through the docs and answers on here and I'm still needing some help:

index.tsx

```js
const getInfiniteArticles = ({ pageParams = 0 }) => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/articles', { params: { page: pageParams } });

  return res.data;
}
```

api/articles.ts

```js
const getArticles = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    const { page } = req.query;
    const pageNum = Number(page);

    const data = await NewsService.getArticles(getRange(pageNum));

    return res.status(200).json({
      data,
      previousPage: pageNum > 0 ? (pageNum - 1) : null,
      nextPage: pageNum + 1,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(err);
    res.status(405).end();
  }
};

export default getArticles;
```

index.tsx

```js
  const { data: articlePages, fetchNextPage } = useInfiniteQuery(
    'infinite-articles', 
    getInfiniteArticles, 
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allGroups) => {
        console.log('lastPage: ', lastPage);
        console.log('allGroups: ', allGroups);
        return lastPage.nextPage;
      }
    });

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    fetchNextPage();
  };
```

console after clicking next page:

```js
lastPage: { data: Array(50), previousPage: null, nextPage: 1}
allGroups: [
{ data: Array(50), previousPage: null, nextPage: 1},
{ data: Array(50), previousPage: null, nextPage: 1},
]
```

Any help on why I'm getting the same groups is appreciated! :)

Comment: your react-query frontend code looks definitely correct, so I would look towards something on the server. also check the network tab about what is being returned from the api. It looks mostly like the page param is not sent to the backend - are you sure that's the way with axios? Why not append the page param to the url and take it from there?

Comment: The backend is getting the right page... but, something is not triggering a new query call. It keeps sending the same page as 0 and getting the same response. So, it's working in the sense that useInfiniteQuery is calling for 2 pages, but it's not updating based on the returned page data... I think, cause when I try to get a console from 'getInfiniteArticles' I only get one log at the beginning and then it fires again... without logging anything as I end up with 2 calls to the backend

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, it turns out my structure wasn't correct

```js
 const {
   fetchNextPage,
   fetchPreviousPage,
   hasNextPage,
   hasPreviousPage,
   isFetchingNextPage,
   isFetchingPreviousPage,
   ...result
 } = useInfiniteQuery(queryKey, ({ pageParam = 1 }) => fetchPage(pageParam), {
   ...options,
   getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allPages) => lastPage.nextCursor,
   getPreviousPageParam: (firstPage, allPages) => firstPage.prevCursor,
 })
```

```js
queryFn: (context: QueryFunctionContext) => Promise<TData>
```

The queryFn is supposed to be a synchronous function that returns a Promise

I was either passing an async function or I was returning the TData not a promise.

updated and working:

```js
const getInfiniteArticles = ({ pageParam = 0 }) => axios.get('/api/articles', { params: { page: pageParam } });
```

```js
const { data: articlePages, fetchNextPage } = useInfiniteQuery('articles', getInfiniteArticles, {
  getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
    // the returned axios response
    return lastPage.data.nextPage;
  }
});
```

[Reference Page](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useInfiniteQuery)

Comment: An async function is also just a function that returns a Promise, so I have doubts that this was it 